# Limit definition for a discrete functions.

Tags: limits

Given $f(x)=x^{2}$ that is only defined for the domain $ \{1,2\}$ .
How do I define the limit in the expression below. The epsilon-delta definition won't work.

$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = 1$

Comment: epsilon-delta definition does work. Take $\delta <1$ to prove this.

Comment: In fact, the limit is any number you want, since the set  $\{x | 0 < |x-1| < 1 \}$ is empty.

Comment: @Kavi It works but why do l take $\delta <1$ . Sorry for being a bit slow.

Comment: In $\{1,2\}$ the condition $|x-1| <1$ implies $x=1$. (actually $\delta=1$ is also fine).

Comment: @copper Since the set is empty, can we say that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @Kavi got it. Can the limit be any number ?

Comment: @AristotleStagiritis: Well, not with the usual definition. It doesn't really matter since your set is discrete, but the limit is any number. It follows directly from the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\lim_{x\to p} g(x)$ requires that $p$ is a limit point of the domain of $g$.

In your example, $p=1$ is not a limit point of the domain of $f$.